# Two values for a parameter in ParametricPlot3D

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions

I'm a bit of a beginner when it comes to Mathematica, so this may be sort of a dumb question, but - I'm working on a problem that requires plotting a, as I quote, "2D torus" using ParametricPlot3D for some reason. I've got the parametric equation with variables as described in the image.

[image]

x = (R1 + R2 cos(v)) cos(u), y = (R1 + R2 cos(v)) sin(u), z = R2 sin(v)
I want R1 to equal 2 and R2 to equal 1.

Now, I figured that for the torus to be two-dimensional, the angle v has to take either the value of 0 or Pi, but the ParametricPlot3D syntax insists that the parameter is defined by a range {v, v_min, v_max}. My code, for now, looks like this:

`ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]}, {v, 0, Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None]`

So now my question is since I'm required to use ParametricPlot3D, is there any way to make the function take on a set of two values instead of a range?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! I think you might be slightly confused: ``v`` has to go from $-\pi$ to $\pi$: ``ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]}, {v, -Pi, Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None]``

Comment: What is probably meant by "2D torus" is exactly the picture you posted. The torus is the surface, and the surface is 2D. So, it's a 2D surface embedded in a 3D space. Therefore, you don't need to try to restrict the angle v to 0 and Pi exactly. Instead, let v range through the full 2Pi radians of a circle (360 degrees).

Answer (score 2):

There are at least two ways to "take on a set of two values". All of them get the same result of `ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]}, {v, 0, Pi}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> None]`

```
value1 = {0, Pi};
value2 = {0, 2 Pi};
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], Sin[v]}, 
 Flatten[{v, value1}], Flatten[{u, value2}], Mesh -> None]
```

```
value1 = {0, Pi};
value2 = {0, 2 Pi};
ParametricPlot3D[{(2 + Cos[v]) Cos[u], (2 + Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
  Sin[v]}, {v, u} ∈ 
  Rectangle @@ Transpose[{value1, value2}]]
```